# Non-trivial data binding

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

Trivial data binding examples are just that, trivial.  I want to do something a little more complicated and am wondering if there's an easy, built in way to handle it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    List<DataStruct> list = new List<DataStruct>()
    {
      new DataStruct(){Name = "Name 1", Value = "Value 1", ComplexValue = new ComplexValue(){Part1 = "1:P1", Part2 = "1:P2"}},
      new DataStruct(){Name = "Name 2", Value = "Value 2", ComplexValue = new ComplexValue(){Part1 = "2:P1", Part2 = "2:P2"}}
    };

    listBox1.DataSource = list;
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "ComplexValue.Part1";
  }
}

public class DataStruct
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
  public ComplexValue ComplexValue { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexValue
{
  public string Part1 { get; set; }
  public string Part2 { get; set; }
}
```

Is there an easy way to get the value of the Part1 property to be set as the display member for a list of DataStruct items?  Above I tried something that I thought made sense, but it just defaults back to the ToString() on DataStruct.  I can work around it if necessary, I was just wondering if there was something built into the data binding that would handle more complex data binding like above.

Edit: Using WinForms

Comment: WinForms or WPF? If it's WPF it's trivial.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps not a built-in way, but you could always define

```
DataStruct {
    public ComplexValuePart1 { 
        get { return ComplexValue.Part1; }
    }
}
```

and set your DisplayMember to that

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd go for a simple solution like Jimmy's - however, if you *want* to do this (with regular win-form bindings), you'd need to use a custom type descriptor to flatten `Part1` / `Part2` as virtual properties of `DataStruct`. You can do this via `ICustomTypeDescriptor` or `TypeDescriptionProvider`. The latter is more involved, but cleaner from a "separation of concerns" viewpoint.

If you really want I can prepare an example (or there are many I've done in the past floating around) - but simple is beautiful: if you only have a few properties, a simple facade (i.e. pass-thru properties on `DataStruct`) would be preferable.